# System freezing for ~20s when window is dragged to edge of screen

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, kde, plasma-5

I updated Ubuntu to 19.04 and now when I drag windows to the edge of the screen my system freezes for 20 seconds or so. I'm using Kubuntu (KDE Plasma).

Nvidia proprietary drivers 418.56

Symptoms match those described here: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/kde-nvidia-stutter-when-window-tiling/82312

Switching the KDE Compositor from OpenGL to XRender fixes the issue but the performance is pretty bad so it's not an ideal solution.

Is there a good solution to this?

Comment: • Please incorporate additional material in the question itself. • You can also try asking at [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net), or [KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org), or [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/) or [reddit/kubuntu](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is caused by this bug:
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=406180

I managed to fix it by running:
`kcmshell5 qtquicksettings` and setting render loop to Basic mode.